# coroutine animation not playing as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so everything seems to be running as far as the AI switching different States, however when it gets in range with the player the State freezes in attack and does not play any Attack Animation, I have created the AI with Bone Rigging, Im wondering if this may be affecting it, here is my script for calling the Animation and the script for one the animation has finished to go back to idleFollow state.

```
        using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeleeWeapon : Weapon
{
    [SerializeField] private float attackDelay = 1f;

    private Collider2D damageAreaCollider2D;
    private Animator animatorAttack;
    private bool attacking;

    private readonly int useMeleeWeapon = Animator.StringToHash(name:"UseMeleeWeapon");

    private void Start()
    {
        damageAreaCollider2D = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        animatorAttack = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //animatorAttack.Play(useMeleeWeapon);
    }
    

    public override void UseWeapon()
    {
        StartCoroutine(routine: Attack());
    }

/*protected override void Update()
{
    base.Update();
    // FlipMeleeWeapon();
}*/


    private IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        if (attacking)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        // Attack
        attacking = true;
        damageAreaCollider2D.enabled = true;
        animatorAttack.Play(useMeleeWeapon);
        


        // Stop Attack
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackDelay);
        damageAreaCollider2D.enabled = false;
        attacking = false;
        
       

    }

    
}
```

```
        using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "AI/Decisions/Attack Completed", fileName = "AttackCompleted")]
public class DecisionAttackCompleted : AIDecision
{
    public override bool Decide(StateController controller)
    {
        return AttackCompleted(controller);
    }

    private bool AttackCompleted(StateController controller)
    {
        if (controller.CharacterWeapon.CurrentWeapon.GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length
        > controller.CharacterWeapon.CurrentWeapon.GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime)
        {
            return true;
        }
        

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the issue, I ended up placing this code into the WeaponMelee script, but now im dealing with a weird glitch where the AI keeps tring to face the left instead of the player when they are close to eachother. this has to do with the boxcollider2D so ive placed a capsulecollider2d inside of him and changed the script to capsulecollider2d as well. but the issue is still happening

```
       private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        StartCoroutine(routine: Attack());
    }
```